# Nunit MySQl Error

Tags: c#, mysql, nunit

MySQL Exception when testing with NUnit. I have installed MySQL Connector 6.6.5 in two machines, however one of the system, when running the same test using Nunit I get the following Error. While in other system its working successfully.

```
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory.get_MySqlDbProviderServicesInstance()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory.System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderServices(DbProviderFactory factory)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.InitializeProviderManifest(Action`3 addError)
at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleAttribute(XmlReader reader)
at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaElement.ParseAttribute(XmlReader reader)
at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaElement.Parse(XmlReader reader)
at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleTopLevelSchemaElement(XmlReader reader)
at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.InternalParse(XmlReader sourceReader, String sourceLocation)
at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.Parse(XmlReader sourceReader, String sourceLocation)
at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.ParseAndValidate(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModel, AttributeValueNotification providerNotification, AttributeValueNotification providerManifestTokenNotification, ProviderManifestNeeded providerManifestNeeded, IList`1& schemaCollection)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.StoreMetadataEntry.LoadStoreCollection(EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader loader)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadItemCollection[T](IItemCollectionLoader`1 itemCollectionLoader, T entry)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetOrCreateStoreAndMappingItemCollections(String cacheKey, MetadataArtifactLoader loader, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Object& entryToken)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.LoadStoreItemCollections(MetadataWorkspace workspace, DbConnection storeConnection, DbProviderFactory factory, DbConnectionOptions connectionOptions, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader artifactLoader)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean initializeAllCollections)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureMetadata()
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery.ToTraceString()
at FreeLance.Data.Framework.EntityFramework.Repository`1.GetSingle(Expression`1 where, Expression`1[] include) in D:\CMS_Org\SonnetCMS\FreeLance\Framework\Data\FreeLance.Data.Framework\EntityFramework\Repository.cs:line 114
at FreeLance.Business.PageBC.GetUserName(Int32 userId) in D:\CMS_Org\SonnetCMS\FreeLance\Business\FreeLance.Business\Admin\PageBC.cs:line 179
at FreeLance.Services.PageService.GetUserName(Int32 userId) in D:\CMS_Org\SonnetCMS\FreeLance\Services\FreeLance.Services\PageService.cs:line 42
at TestCMS.Class1.Test()
```

**EDIT :**

Function Where I get the error:

```
public virtual TEntity GetSingle(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] include)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = this.dbSet.Where(where);
            if (include != null)
            {
                query = this.dbSet.Include<TEntity>(include).Where(where);
            }

            Debug.Write(query.ToString());

            return query.SingleOrDefault<TEntity>();
        }
```

**Exception:**

Source : `MySql.Data`

Error : `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Declaring Type : `{Name = "MySqlClientFactory" FullName = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory"}`

Assembly : `{MySql.Data, Version=6.6.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d}`

in the function this.dbset has NullReferenceException, while in the system which is working correct I have this.dbset,

```
"{SELECT
`Extent1`.`UserID`, 
`Extent1`.`UserGUID`, 
`Extent1`.`UserCode`, 
`Extent1`.`UserAuthentication`, 
`Extent1`.`UserType`, 
`Extent1`.`UserPassword`, 
`Extent1`.`UserPasswordSalt`, 
`Extent1`.`UserFirstName`, 
`Extent1`.`UserMiddleName`, 
`Extent1`.`UserLastName`, 
`Extent1`.`UserCompanyName`,
`Extent1`.`IsUserNeedToResetPasswordNextLogin`, 
`Extent1`.`UserPasswordExpiryDate`, 
`Extent1`.`UserLoginFailAttempts`, 
`Extent1`.`UserLoginFailDate`, 
`Extent1`.`UserPasswordResetDate`, 
`Extent1`.`UserPasswordResetBy`, 
`Extent1`.`UserLastLoginDate`, 
`Extent1`.`IsUserLoginLocked`, 
`Extent1`.`UserLoginLockedDate`, 
`Extent1`.`IsForUserSecurityQuestionRequired`, 
`Extent1`.`Remarks`, 
`Extent1`.`IsActive`, 
`Extent1`.`CreatedBy`, 
`Extent1`.`CreatedDate`, 
`Extent1`.`UpdatedBy`, 
`Extent1`.`UpdatedDate`
FROM `isuser` AS `Extent1`}"
```

Comment: This is just a stack trace.  What's the type and the message of the exception?

Comment: Please have a look updated qstn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Web.Config we changed the DB provider Factory, MySQL Connector version from 6.6.5 to 6.6.6. That solved our issue.